# how to lock down release pipepline Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a requirement to prevent changes to the part of a release pipeline that releases to databases.

in my release pipeline, I have 2 release agent jobs, one for the database, one for the application.   The agentpool that runs the database release has (necessarily) sysadmin perms on Prod servers, and I want to make sure that no-one (other than DBA's) have access to change that part AgentJob in the pipeline.   (but still have others make changes to other parts of the job)

Currently I've limited agent pool with perms to the DBA team, but when the other devs view the pipeline, it shows errors because they dont have perms to the pools that can deploy the db (and as such cannot update *any* part of the pipeline)

[image: Devops Server Pipeline]

Answer (score 1):

@Trubs, I believe you are talking about stage level security. You can easily protect your production stage by setting proper pipeline stage security
[Specify stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)

Devs will see a message like below
[image: Pipeline stage security]